# can´t find the bug in my code....Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have a problem with a my code. When at the time I run it, it crashes... When I´m debugging it says it´s a "Segmentation fault" error. But I cannot find the bug. 
Here´s the code:

**listaArchivo.H (header)**

```
    #ifndef LISTAARCHIVOS_H
    #define LISTAARCHIVOS_H

    #include "Archivo.h"

    struct _listaArchivos{
        Archivo arch;
    };
    typedef _listaArchivos* ListaArchivos;

/*
 * creates and initializes a new lista of archivos.
 */
    ListaArchivos crearListaArchivos(){
        ListaArchivos *lista;

        (*lista)->arch=NULL;

       return *lista;
    }

/*
 * inserts 'archivo' in 'lista'.
 */
    void insertarArchivoListaArchivos(ListaArchivos &lista, Archivo archivo){
        Archivo *nuevoArchivo;
        nuevoArchivo=new Archivo;
        *nuevoArchivo=archivo;
        if (lista==NULL){
            lista->arch=*nuevoArchivo;
            lista->arch->Anterior=NULL;
            lista->arch->Siguiente=NULL;
        }
    }
```

**"Archivo.h" (header)**

```
   #ifndef ARCHIVO_H
    #define ARCHIVO_H
    struct _archivo{
        Cadena nombreArchivo;
        Cadena Atributos;
        Cadena Contenido;
        _archivo *Siguiente;
        _archivo *Anterior;
    };
    typedef _archivo* Archivo;

/*
 * Crea e inicializa un archivo con nombre 'nombreArchivo'
 */
    Archivo crearArchivo(Cadena nombreArchivo){

        Archivo *nuevoArchivo;
        nuevoArchivo=new Archivo;

        (*nuevoArchivo)->Atributos="Lectura/Escritura";
        (*nuevoArchivo)->Contenido=NULL;
        (*nuevoArchivo)->nombreArchivo=nombreArchivo;
        (*nuevoArchivo)->Siguiente=NULL;
        (*nuevoArchivo)->Anterior=NULL;

        return *nuevoArchivo;
    }
```

@Vishnu Kanwar 
Here's the code from where Im calling the function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>

#include "Sistema.h"
#include "Archivo.h"
#include "Directorio.h"
#include "ListaArchivos.h"
#include "Constantes.h"
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    /* VARS */
    Cadena c_DIR=(char *)"DIR";
    Cadena c_CREATEFILE=(char *)"CREATEFILE";
    Cadena c_DELETE=(char *)"DELETE";
    Cadena c_ATTRIB=(char *)"ATTRIB";
    Cadena c_IF=(char *)"IF";
    Cadena c_DF=(char *)"DF";
    Cadena c_TYPE=(char *)"TYPE";
    Cadena c_CREARSISTEMA=(char *)"CREARSISTEMA";
    Cadena c_DESTRUIRSISTEMA=(char *)"DESTRUIRSISTEMA";
    Cadena c_EXIT=(char *)"EXIT";
    Cadena Segmento;
    Cadena comando;
    Cadena parametro1;
    Cadena parametro2;
    bool seguir;
    int contador=0;
    char frase[50];
    Archivo *arch;
    ListaArchivos *lista;

    /* DO WHILE UNTILL BOOL=TRUE */
    do{
    cout <<"> ";

    /* ALGORITHM FOR DIVIDING THE FRASE IN TOKENS */
    fgets(frase,50,stdin);
    Segmento=strtok(frase," ");
    while(Segmento!=NULL){
             if( contador == 0 ){
                 comando=Segmento; /* GUARDA EL COMANDO */
             }
             if ( contador == 1 ){
                  parametro1=Segmento; /* GUARDA EL PRIMER PARAMETRO */
             }
             if( contador == 2 ){
                 parametro2=Segmento; /* GUARDA EL SEGUNDO PARAMETRO */
             }
             Segmento=strtok(NULL, " ");
             contador++;
    }

    /* SELECTS "COMANDO" COMPARING WITH THE OTHER CHAR* */
    if (strcmp(comando,c_DIR)== 0){
        cout <<"Uso comando DIR"<<endl<<endl;
    }
    else{
        if (strcmp(comando,c_CREATEFILE)== 0){ **/*HERE IS WHERE I MAKE THE CALLS*/**

            *lista=crearListaArchivos();


            cout<<"LISTA CREATED SUCCESSFULLY !!"<<endl;

            *arch=crearArchivo(parametro1);
            cout<<"ARCHIVO CREATED"<<endl;

            insertarArchivoListaArchivos(*lista,*arch);

            cout <<"THE ARCHIVO WAS ADDED SUCCESFULLY !!"<<endl<<endl;
        }
        else{
            if (strcmp(comando,c_DELETE)== 0){
                cout <<"Uso comando DELETE "<<endl<<endl;
            }
            else{
                if (strcmp(comando,c_ATTRIB)== 0){
                    cout <<"Uso comando ATTRIB"<<endl<<endl;
                }
                else{
                    if (strcmp(comando,c_IF)== 0){
                        cout <<"Uso comando IF"<<endl<<endl;
                    }
                    else{
                        if (strcmp(comando,c_DF)== 0){
                            cout <<"Uso comando DF"<<endl<<endl;
                        }
                        else{
                            if (strcmp(comando,c_TYPE)== 0) {
                                cout <<"Uso comando TYPE"<<endl<<endl;
                            }
                            else{
                                if (strcmp(comando,c_CREARSISTEMA)== 0){
                                    cout <<"Uso comando CREARSISTEMA"<<endl<<endl;
                                }
                                else{
                                    if (strcmp(comando,c_DESTRUIRSISTEMA)== 0){
                                        cout <<"Uso comando DESTRUIRSISTEMA"<<endl<<endl;
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        if (strcmp(comando,c_EXIT)==0){
                                            cout <<"Saliendo del programa..."<<endl<<endl;
                                            seguir=false;
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            cout << "Comando incorrecto."<<endl<<endl;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                             }
                          }
                       }
                   }
                }
            }
        }
    }while(seguir);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem starts WHEN I call functions crearArchivo and crearListaArchivo in main. The rest seems to be working fine. 
If you have any idea of how I can solve this bug, please help me. **Thank you VERY MUCH!** :)

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code using a debugger to see where the fault happens?

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings. You should get one on the line `(*lista)->arch=NULL;` — read it!

Comment: also, `*lista` defines a pointer to a list but doesn't allocate memory for it. Dereferencing it is UB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ListaArchivos crearListaArchivos(){
    ListaArchivos *lista;
```

above *lista* is a `_listaArchivos**` and that to uninitialized in your code.
As a fix (to execute next line of your code successfully) you need to initialize memory pointed by `lista`

```
`lista=new ListaArchivos`
```

Wait! so far we have a valid `_listaArchivos*` but not `_listaArchivos` to make it valid you also need to do:

```
*lista = new _listaArchivos;
```

now `*lista` points to a valid object of _listaArchivos in memory and you can execute rest of your code which uses (*lista).

```
    (*lista)->arch=NULL;

   return *lista;
}
```

*EDIT*:
Even-though two `new` fixes allocation issue but this style of coding makes garbage collection a challenge and very hard to manage.

Comment: ListaArchivos crearListaArchivos(){
       ListaArchivos *lista = new ListaArchivos;

        (*lista)->arch=NULL;

       return *lista;
}
Right now it's like this, I think I have allocated the memory, but still the bug persists

Comment: no you haven't. memory is allocated only once while you need to memory allocations as suggested in above answer

Comment: @Bastian: crearListaArchivos(){ ListaArchivos *lista = new ListaArchivos; (*lista) = new _listaArchivos; (*lista)->arch=NULL; return *lista; }

Comment: I see, I see... I made your suggested changes, but it's still crushing when I call the function. How weird.

Comment: In that case the crash is somewhere else. Could you please share the code which is calling crearListaArchivos?

Answer (score 0):

```
 ListaArchivos crearListaArchivos(){
        ListaArchivos *lista;

        (*lista)->arch=NULL;

       return *lista;
    }
```

Does not create anything.
It just declares a variable and return it. This is not a very good way.

Try something like.

```
 ListaArchivos crearListaArchivos(){
        ListaArchivos *lista = new ListaArchivos();

        lista->arch=NULL;

       return *lista;
    }
```

And read on pointers, memory, and of course, this link here

[resource aquisition is initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)

Comment: still bugged, it's a double pointer, it needs two allocations

Comment: Where do you see a "**" here? NULL is perfectly legal for arch. At least from the snippet in the question.

Comment: It´s still bugged, yes. You see, what I have to do is to make a list of struct _archivo, the type for this list is listaArchivo. 

In crearListaArchivos() the idea is to declare, initialize and return the list "lista" of _archivo.

Comment: @MareInfinitus c'mon, you don't need any `**` - after all, `typedef _listaArchivos* ListaArchivos;` so `lista->arch=NULL` won't even compile

Comment: .. SO. I made a few changes to the function crearListaArchivos(), now, the problem seems to be somewhere else, becouse when I debug the program, the error: "Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault." seems to be in crearArchivo(cadena nombreArchivo);